# How can I use the conditional operator to print an integer or a string value

Tags: c, printf, conditional-operator

In C how can I use a conditional operator inside of a printf statement utilizing two different data types?  I would like to have the code below printing nothing instead of zero each time it encounters a even number.  I would also like to be able to print a string when it encounters certain numbers.

I tried type casting (char)list[i] but that results in an incompatiable type cast because the printf statement requires an integer.

## Print only odd values

```
int fail = 0;

    int list[] = {1, 2, 3, -1, 4};
    int size = sizeof(list) / sizeof(list[0]);

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if(list[i] == -1) {
            break;
        }
        printf("%d\n", (list[i] % 2 == 0) ? (i) : (fail));
    }
```

Comment: Why not use `if` statements to choose between appropriate `printf` statements?

Comment: you could use the same `?` operator to choose between "%s" and "%d" as your format specifier string...

Comment: How would the ? operator work inside the format specifier?

Comment: something like `printf((list[i] % 2 == 0) ? "%s\n" : "%d\n",` ...

Comment: @bruceg: which will end up evaluating the conditional twice, no? It's only a small step to `(list[i]%2?printf("%d\n", i);printf("%s\n", "odd");` :)

Comment: @rici true... but he wants one printf. You could calculate `int is_even = (list[i] % 2 == 0);` before the printf, and use the saved value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct and readable approach is to use several calls to `printf`, each with its own format and arguments:

```
if (list[i] % 2 == 0) {
  printf("%d\n", i);
}
else if (i == 42) {
  puts("The answer");
}
/* Otherwise, print nothing */
```

You could also do that with the `?:` operator:

```
(list[i] % 2 == 0) ? printf("%d\n", i) :
(i = 42)           ? printf("%s\n", "The answer") :
                     0;
```

(This works because all three possible return values are the number of characters printed.)

If you just want to print 0 as nothing instead of `0`, use 0 as the *precision* (not the width) of the format specifier:

```
printf("%.0d\n", i);
```

(In obfuscated code, you could force the value you wanted to hide to be 0 with a ternary operator. Or even with a multiply.)

C is a strongly-typed language, which means that the compiler needs to be able to deduce the type of any expression. That includes `?:` expressions, so it is not possible for the second and third arguments of that operator to have incompatible types.